# Stack Overflow logo weird styling in SO Japanese users tab

Tags: bug, design, international-sites

The regular logo is shown in the [users tab:](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)

> [image: normal logo]

But when going to a [specific user's page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/26370/kunif) it's cut off:

> [image: "スタック・オーバーフロー" cut off]

I use Chrome.

Comment: No repro here. What browser you have, and what OS exactly?

Comment: I guess it is about chang `height` or `background-position` of `.top-bar .-logo .-img`

Comment: @Xufox try with Private/Incognito mode of your browser. (Bug happens on all browsers when not logged in, afaik.)

Comment: @Xufox well, dunno why exactly, some missing/extra elements, didn't dig into it. But with Chrome, it's bugged when not logged in and fine when logged in. As the original report say, in some browsers it's even worse and always bugged. If you got Chrome, give it a try and see.

Comment: Okay, it’s reproducible in Firefox Nightly 66.0a1, too. I overlooked the _“But when going to a specific user's page”_ part. Haven’t had my coffee yet…